# How do I make the Napili template home page public for all users?

Tags: community, lightning-community, community-builder, napili

Using the Napili template in Communities, how do I make the landing page/home page  public alongside all its components?

I have already made the Community Page access Public through public settings, I have also checked public can access the community.
However, not all the components are available.

Comment: Which component you are not able to access without login?

Comment: @Kaushikee did you resolve this?

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if it was of help in resolving your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your community builder, under settings:
[image]

Additionally, you can add which profiles can access from community management > Administration > Members:
[image]

Additionally, you have to give read permissions to the profile(s) on the objects you use in your components.